# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined arrays typescript

Tags: typescript, undefined

Here is my code :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.http.get<any>(this.getInfoArtiste)
  .subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.artist.name);
    console.log(response.artist.image[5]['#text']);
    this.artiste.nom = response.artist.name;
    this.artiste.image = response.artist.image[5]['#text'];
    this.artiste.albums = [];
    console.log(this.artiste.albums);
  });

/* Get les albums de l'artiste */
this.http.get<any>(this.getAlbums)
  .subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
    for (let i = 0; i < response.topalbums.album.length; i++) {
      this.artiste.albums.push(new 

Album(response.topalbums.album[i].name, response.topalbums.album[i].image[3]['#text'], null ));
        }
        console.log(this.artiste.albums);
      });

/*    Get les chansons des albums*/
     for ( let a = 0; a < this.artiste.albums.length; a++) {
       this.http.get<any>('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=9a8a3facebbccaf363bb9fd68fa37abf&artist=' + this.artisteSelect + '&album=' + this.artiste.albums[a].name + '&format=json')
         .subscribe(response => {
           console.log(response);
         });
     }
      }
```

The problem is when i get to the last for() it says that albums is undefined however i used it in my push and with the console.log i can see its not empty

Comment: Maybe `this.artiste.albums` is not an array? Post the output of the `console.log(this.artiste.albums);`.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your `artiste.albums` inside of a subscribe callback. The for loop will execute before the http request is finished.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  // Initialize array outside of subscription. The array won't be initialized until the observable completes.
  this.artiste.albums = [];

  this.http.get<any>(this.getInfoArtiste)
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.artiste.nom = response.artist.name;
      this.artiste.image = response.artist.image[5]['#text'];
    });

   this.http.get<any>(this.getAlbums)
     .subscribe(response => {
        for (let i = 0; i < response.topalbums.album.length; i++) {
          this.artiste.albums.push(new Album(response.topalbums.album[i].name, response.topalbums.album[i].image[3]['#text'], null ));
        }
     });

    for ( let a = 0; a < this.artiste.albums.length; a++) {
      this.http.get<any>('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=9a8a3facebbccaf363bb9fd68fa37abf&artist=' + this.artisteSelect + '&album=' + this.artiste.albums[a].name + '&format=json')
        .subscribe(response => {
          console.log(response);
        });
    }
  }
```